# IDFCollection to java.util.Collection or ArrayList

Tags: java, documentum, dfc, documentum-dfc

How can I retrieve and store the values from IDFCollection to java.util.Collection or ArrayList. Is there any direct way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate IDfCollection using `IDfCollection.next()` method.
If `next()` returns `true`, then you can access returned row of data by using getter methods of IDfCollection. When you call `next()` again, it will move to the next row (if any).
Usually reading from collection is done in while loop:

```
while(col.next())
{
  String value1 = col.getString("column1");
}
```

To store values to a list - just create an instance before `while` and fill it inside the loop.